# How to store an object of variable type in a field in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have created an object in Java, called "Edge". This object is a directed edge for a graph that stores a reference to the node at its start and the node at its end.

These nodes are currently a "Vertex" object, however I would like to also store the origin of the dual edge in the same object, so that it would return a "Face" object instead. Currently I only support returning a Vertex, as shown in the code below.

```
public class Edge{

    private Vertex org; //this is the line that I want to be able to store a 
                        //face given certain conditions (the index being 1 or 3)

    private Face left;  //this is a line where I want to store a face normally
                        //but store a Vertex if this is a dual edge

    private int index;  //a number from 0-3, where 1 and 3 are in the dual graph

    public Vertex Org(){
        return org;
    }

}
```

I was wondering if there was a way of defining the function Org() and the field org, in such a way that the it could either be a Face or a Vertex. I was wondering if there was a way of using generic types, that could take become a "Vertex" or a "Face" depending on the index parameter. An example of what I tried is below.

```
public class Edge<T>{

    public T org;

    private T Org(){
        return org;
    }

}
```

However, this does not seem a very elegant solution and it only works for getting the origin and not the left Face/Vertex.

I was wondering if there was a way of storing a field that can be one of two possible object types, or another simple way of getting around this problem.

Comment: have you looked at interface solutions as well? or are they not wanted for one of another reason?

Comment: No I have not yet tried that. I am not sure how that will solve the problem as the problem is returning different types of objects. I am not sure how using an interface would fix that problem. I will look into it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to return totally different types of objects from the same method, because what would you do with them after you returned them?

Suppose you did:

```
Object faceOrVertex = edge.org(); // returns face or vertex
```

So now you have to decide what to do with your face or vertex. You will need to write:

```
if (faceOrVertex instanceof Face) {
    // cast to Face and do face stuff
} else {
    // cast to Vertex and do vertex stuff
}
```

You might as well call two different methods returning known types.

Generics won't help you here. They don't remove the need for different types.

If your `Face` and `Vertex` classes have common features and you want to treat them in a common way, the solution is two declare an interface with common methods and have the `Face` and `Vertex` classes implement those methods. Without knowing exactly what you want to do with the result of the `org` method though, it is impossible to recommend something.

I suggest you first implement the solution with two different methods and then perhaps look later for common blocks of code that you could refactor into shared logic.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Vertex` and `Face` are two different types, so a single method is never going to work, unless you have an interface that both `Vertex` and `Face` implements. Say you have defined an interface `GraphElement`. Now your class would bocome something like:

```
public interface GraphElement {
    // operations
}

class Edge<V extends GraphElement, F extends GraphElement> {
    V vertex;
    F face;
    int index;

    GraphElement org() {
        // processing code
        return index % 2 == 0 ? face : vertex;
    }
}
```